# Java CompareTo for objects not Working

Tags: java, compare, equals, priority-queue, compareto

```
public class Book implements Comparable<Book>, Serializable{
int numberOfPages;
boolean hardback;
String title;
double price;

public Book (int numberOfPages,boolean hardback, String title,double price)throws          BookException {
    setNumberOfPages(numberOfPages);
    setHardback(hardback);
    setPrice(price);
    setTitle(title);
}
public int getNumberOfPages(){
    return numberOfPages;
}
public void setNumberOfPages(int numberOfPages) throws BookException {
    if(numberOfPages < 1){
        throw new BookException("Pages must be a positive integer");
    }
    this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
}
public boolean isHardback(){
    return hardback;
}
public void setHardback(boolean hardback) {
    this.hardback = hardback;
}
public String getTitle(){
       return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) throws BookException {
    if (title == null || title.isEmpty()){
      throw new BookException("No title must be less than 0 characters");
    }
    this.title = title;
}
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) throws BookException {
    if (price < 0){
        throw new BookException("Price can't be negative");
    }
    this.price = price;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Book o){
    int Before =  -1;
    int Equal =  0;
    int After =  1;
    if (this == o) return Equal;
    if (this.getNumberOfPages() < o.getNumberOfPages()) return Before;
    if (this.getNumberOfPages() > o.getNumberOfPages()) return After;
    if (this.getPrice() < o.getPrice()) return After;
    if (this.getPrice() > o.getPrice()) return Before;
    int comparison = this.getTitle().compareTo(o.getTitle());
    if (comparison != Equal) return comparison;
    return Equal;
}
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false;

    Book that = (Book)o;
    return
            ( this.numberOfPages == that.numberOfPages ) &&
                    ( this.price == that.price ) &&
                    ( this.title.equals(that.title) )
            ;
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Title " + getTitle());
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("Number Of Pages " + getNumberOfPages());
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("Is Hardback " + isHardback());
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append("Price " + getPrice());
        sb.append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
 }
```

When I run this code the order is all messed up as if the compareTo is not working.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class BookQueue {
public static void main(String[] args)throws BookException  {

        PriorityQueue<Book> pq = new PriorityQueue<Book>();
        pq.offer(new Book(22, true,"Cat in the hat", 10));
        pq.offer(new Book(32, true,"Green eggs and ham", 12));
        pq.offer(new Book(42, true,"Hop on Pop", 11));
        pq.offer(new Book(20, true,"Lorax", 19));
        pq.offer(new Book(20, false,"Lorax", 19));

        Iterator itr = pq.iterator();
        System.out.println("\n");
        while(itr.hasNext()){
           System.out.println(itr.next());
        }


}
```

}

**This is the output:**

It should order it by lowest number of pages then price then title
It starts off well form 20 but then goes to 42 then 32 and 22?

```
Title Lorax
Number Of Pages **20**
Is Hardback true
Price 19.0

Title Lorax
Number Of Pages **20**
Is Hardback false
Price 19.0

Title Hop on Pop
Number Of Pages **42**
Is Hardback true
Price 11.0

Title Green eggs and ham
Number Of Pages **32**
Is Hardback true
Price 12.0

Title Cat in the hat
Number Of Pages **22**
Is Hardback true
Price 10.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PriorityQueue` class does not guarantee the order if `iterator()` method is used.

Javadoc explicitly defines it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) as:

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

You just need to modify the `main` as below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class BookQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BookException {

        PriorityQueue<Book> pq = new PriorityQueue<Book>();
        pq.offer(new Book(32, true, "Green eggs and ham", 12));
        pq.offer(new Book(42, true, "Hop on Pop", 11));
        pq.offer(new Book(20, true, "Lorax", 19));
        pq.offer(new Book(20, false, "Lorax", 19));
        pq.offer(new Book(22, true, "Cat in the hat", 10));

        // Iterator itr = pq.iterator();
        // System.out.println("\n");
        // while(itr.hasNext()){
        //   System.out.println(itr.next());
        //}

        Book[] books = new Book[pq.size()];
        Arrays.sort(pq.toArray(books));
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(books[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Also you can try to implement the `Comparator` and pass into the `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator)` if you need different sorting approaches as detailed in [Comparator vs Comparable](http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html).

Comment: Didn't think about doing this but i tried to implement the comparator and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Use this `compareTo()` method.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Book o){
    if (this.getNumberOfPages() != o.getNumberOfPages()) 
         return   new Integer(this.getNumberOfPages()).compareTo(o.getNumberOfPages());    
    if (this.getPrice() != o.getPrice()) 
        return   new Double(this.getPrice()).compareTo(o.getPrice());    
    if(!this.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(o.getTitle()))
        return this.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getTitle());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem wasn't with the campareTo but the way the PriorityQueue works